# How do resample pandas.DataFrame (a week) to averaged Day

Tags: python, pandas, average, resampling

I have data from several days (or even weeks) taken at exactly the same time intervals each day and want to compute an average day time curve.
I tried daily average so far, but than I had one average value for each day... What I need is one value averaged over all available days at each available time. Most probably really easy knowing the right commands. Unfortunately I am quite new to pandas.
Even just a hint where to look in the documentation would be great!

```
Time                   some value

2010-08-31 12:30:00    33.910
2010-08-31 12:40:00    33.250
2010-08-31 12:50:00    30.500
2010-08-31 13:00:00    27.065
2010-08-31 13:10:00    25.610
...

2013-06-07 02:10:00    16.970
2013-06-07 02:20:00    16.955
2013-06-07 02:30:00    17.000
2013-06-07 02:40:00    17.015
2013-06-07 02:50:00    16.910
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `hours` and `minutes` and [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) `mean`:

```
print df
                  Time  some value
0  2010-08-31 12:30:00      33.910
1  2010-08-31 12:40:00      33.250
2  2010-08-31 12:50:00      30.500
3  2010-08-31 13:00:00      27.065
4  2010-08-31 13:10:00      25.610
5  2013-06-07 02:10:00      16.970
6  2013-06-07 02:20:00      16.955
7  2013-06-07 02:30:00      17.000
8  2013-06-07 02:40:00      17.015
9  2013-06-07 02:50:00      16.910

#convert column time to datetime
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
#set index from column Time
df = df.set_index('Time')
print df
                     some value
Time                           
2010-08-31 12:30:00      33.910
2010-08-31 12:40:00      33.250
2010-08-31 12:50:00      30.500
2010-08-31 13:00:00      27.065
2010-08-31 13:10:00      25.610
2013-06-07 02:10:00      16.970
2013-06-07 02:20:00      16.955
2013-06-07 02:30:00      17.000
2013-06-07 02:40:00      17.015
2013-06-07 02:50:00      16.910
```

```
print df.groupby([df.index.hour, df.index.minute])['some value'].transform('mean')
Time
2010-08-31 12:30:00    33.910
2010-08-31 12:40:00    33.250
2010-08-31 12:50:00    30.500
2010-08-31 13:00:00    27.065
2010-08-31 13:10:00    25.610
2013-06-07 02:10:00    16.970
2013-06-07 02:20:00    16.955
2013-06-07 02:30:00    17.000
2013-06-07 02:40:00    17.015
2013-06-07 02:50:00    16.910
dtype: float64
```

Next solution not set `index` to `Datetimeindex`, use [`dt.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html) and [`dt.minute`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.minute.html) and create new column `newCol`:

```
print df
                  Time  some value
0  2010-08-31 12:30:00      33.910
1  2010-08-31 12:40:00      33.250
2  2010-08-31 12:50:00      30.500
3  2010-08-31 13:00:00      27.065
4  2010-08-31 13:10:00      25.610
5  2013-06-07 02:10:00      16.970
6  2013-06-07 02:20:00      16.955
7  2013-06-07 02:30:00      17.000
8  2013-06-07 02:40:00      17.015
9  2013-06-07 02:50:00      16.910

#convert column time to datetime
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
print df
                 Time  some value
0 2010-08-31 12:30:00      33.910
1 2010-08-31 12:40:00      33.250
2 2010-08-31 12:50:00      30.500
3 2010-08-31 13:00:00      27.065
4 2010-08-31 13:10:00      25.610
5 2013-06-07 02:10:00      16.970
6 2013-06-07 02:20:00      16.955
7 2013-06-07 02:30:00      17.000
8 2013-06-07 02:40:00      17.015
9 2013-06-07 02:50:00      16.910
```

```
df['newCol'] = df.groupby([df['Time'].dt.hour, df['Time'].dt.minute])['some value']
                 .transform('mean')
print df
                 Time  some value  newCol
0 2010-08-31 12:30:00      33.910  33.910
1 2010-08-31 12:40:00      33.250  33.250
2 2010-08-31 12:50:00      30.500  30.500
3 2010-08-31 13:00:00      27.065  27.065
4 2010-08-31 13:10:00      25.610  25.610
5 2013-06-07 02:10:00      16.970  16.970
6 2013-06-07 02:20:00      16.955  16.955
7 2013-06-07 02:30:00      17.000  17.000
8 2013-06-07 02:40:00      17.015  17.015
9 2013-06-07 02:50:00      16.910  16.910
```

Comment: Probably, should be  `[df.index.hour, df.index.minute]` in groupby. Read: *one value averaged over all available days at each available time*

Comment: @jezrael What you propose seems to give a single value for all datapoints of one day, so instead of a curve that has the average of 7 days at each time step it has the average of each day at each time step of that very day. So I would have a 7 level plot :-)

Comment: So can be `[df.index.hour, df.index.minute]` or not? What is recommended output?

Comment: I was writing my comment, while the other arrived, [df.index.hour, df.index.minute] seems to do the trick, thx

Comment: @cattt84 - do you need overwrite column `some_value`  by new values? Or add new column with new values?